# WiFi connection via android

Tags: java, android, wifi

I need a tutorial on how to process data on android via wifi. F.e., I need to send some message to PC and receive some other message. How should I establish the connection? What should I do to be able to transfer data and how?

Sorry for the dummy question, but I can't find good manual. I'll be grateful for as detailed manual as possible, or for ome simple example on etablishing wifi connection and sending/receiving simple mesages.

Comment: Learn Socket Programming. There's nothing special about `Wifi` on Android. It's basic Socket Communication.

Comment: If Wifi is enabled and you are connected to the Network, just use Java Socket classes for network communication.

Comment: Then how can I connect to wifi network? I haven't found any connect() method() in API.

Comment: You have to Learn P2P Connection Programming

Comment: I posted snippets of code [here, how to connect to wireless][1]. It maybe will help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973872/how-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network-in-android/12975100#12975100

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You don't have to use any API for connect to wifi its only requires if you want to manually start your wifi in device,**

Just make sure your device has a WiFi enable, and make a **simple TCP/IP Socket application**. With this you can communication with your system and device, And Use System's public IP to connect with your system.

Also don't forget to give `permission Internet` in your manifest file..

Here some nice links for Socket Programing in Android..

[Simple connection example part II - TCP communication](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication)

[Networking with Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/)

[Simple communication using java.net.Socket](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/simple-communication-using.html)

http://www.anddev.org/tcp_sockets-t276.html

http://www.anddev.org/socket_programming-t325-s30.html

**EDIT::** Android WiFi examples,

[Scan for Wireless Networks](http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks)

[Using WiFi API](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html)

SO Question [Android: Is there any way to get notified when known wifi networks get in/out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983214/android-is-there-any-way-to-get-notified-when-known-wifi-networks-get-in-out-of)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I need my application to scan for available wifi networks and connect to the proper one, defined, f.e., by name? Can it be done "inside" my application?

Comment: And the last question. I get IP address via wifiInfo.getIpAddress();, IP address here is int. How can I convert it to be able to use it in socket.open(host, port)? Here host is either String or InetAddress.