# How to get notified when a Open wifi network is available

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, wifi, background-service

I have an app in which whenever users is in range of a particular Wifi. I want to give a notification to the user he is in the wifi zone and can connect to this wifi and start the app. This wifi is an open wifi.

I tried using broadcast receiver with statically registering in AndroidManifest.xml.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

WifiReceiver:

```
if (_wifiManager == null)
            _wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        if (_wifiManager.IsWifiEnabled)
        {
            var results = _wifiManager.ScanResults;
            if (results.Any(x => x.Ssid == "MyWifiName"))
            {
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher_rounded)
                    .SetContentText("Your are in wifi zone. Start the app")
                    .SetContentTitle("My App");

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
                notificationManager.Notify(1,mBuilder.Build());
            }
        }
```

Now this works only when either I change the currently connected network or if the wifi state is changed i.e it is turned on or off.

Precisely I want to detect if a new wifi (Open) network becomes available I want to check its name and if it is my wifi I want to show the notification.

I am not inclined in using a service that would be my last resort using an alarm

EDIT: how does android show the notification for open wifi networks are available. The ideal case for me to search if wifi is available is whenever android notifies this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get notified when known SSIS wifi networks get in/out of range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983214/is-there-any-way-to-get-notified-when-known-ssis-wifi-networks-get-in-out-of-ran)